# Code structure for multiple applications with a common core

Tags: source-code, project-structure, projects-and-solutions

I want to create two applications that will have a lot of common functionality. Basically, one system is a more advanced version of the other system. Let's call them `Simple` and `Advanced`. The `Advanced` system will add to, extend, alter and sometimes replace the functionality of the `Simple` system. For instance, the `Advanced` system will add new classes, add properties and methods to existing `Simple` classes, change the behavior of classes, etc.

Initially I was thinking that the `Advanced` classes simply inherited from the `Simple` classes but I can see the functionality diverging quite significantly as development progresses, even while maintaining a core base functionality. For instance, the `Simple` system might have a Project class with a Sponsor property whereas the `Advanced` system has a list of Project.Sponsors. It seems poor practice to inherit from a class and then hide, alter or throw away significant parts of its features.

An alternative is just to run two separate code bases and copy the common code between them but that seems inefficient, archaic and fraught with peril. Surely we have moved beyond the days of "copy-and-paste inheritance".

Another way to structure it would be to use partial classes and have three projects: `Core` which has the common functionality, `Simple` which extends the `Core` partial classes for the simple system, and `Advanced` which also extends the `Core` partial classes for the advanced system. Plus having three test projects as well for each system. This seems like a cleaner approach.

What would be the best way to structure the solution/projects/code to create two versions of a similar system? Let's say I later want to create a third system called `Extreme`, largely based on the `Advanced` system. Do I then create an `AdvancedCore` project which both `Advanced` and `Extreme` extend using partial classes? Is there a better way to do this?

If it matters, this is likely to be a C#/MVC system but I'd be happy to do this in any language/framework that is suitable.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach here is to have the Model of the MVC triad in a separate, common project. This Model should provide all the model features that are needed by the various versions. But the model should *not* implement the restrictions that differentiate the `Simple` version from the `Advanced` version.
To take your example, if the `Advanced` version supports multiple Sponsors for a project, and the `Simple` version only one Sponsor, then the model should cater for a list of Sponsors, even though this is less efficient for the `Simple` version.

For each version, you create a separate project containing the View and Controller parts of the MVC triad. This is also where you put the version-specific restrictions in, like having only a single Sponsor for a Project in the `Simple` version.

Comment: I don't think this works as the model is where the functionality will differ. For instance, let's say the `Simple` system uses cash accounting and the `Advanced` system uses accrual accounting - this is a fundamental difference in the behavior at the model level and having a slightly different controller isn't going to help.

Comment: @AzraelSeraphin: Depending on the number of such fundamental differences, either the model could support both options (leaving one unused in the different versions), or there isn't enough common functionality to consider sharing it.

Comment: So your suggestion would be to run two seperate code bases and copy code between them as needed even though more than half the functionality will be shared?

Comment: @AzraelSeraphin: If more than half the functionality is shared, I recommend using a single codebase for the model that supports the union of the functionalities of the different versions.